# Encoding::CompatibilityError in Ruby "<<" string operator

Tags: ruby, string, character-encoding

Please, explain me strange behaviour of strings

```
[22] pry(main)> s = ""
=> ""
[23] pry(main)> s << BCD.encode_to_s(99)
=> "\x99"
[24] pry(main)> s << BCD.encode_to_s(457701)
=> "\x99Ew\x01"
[30] pry(main)> "\x99" << BCD.encode_to_s(457701)
=> "\x99Ew\u0001"
```

So, 24 and 30 answers are not the same.

BCD.encode_to_s

```
#arg as Numeric > 0, even digits ("3456"=good, "345"=bad)
def encode_to_s(arg)
  arg.to_s.bytes.each_slice(2).to_a.inject(""){|str, chunk| str << (chunk[0].chr+chunk[1].chr).to_i(16).chr}
end
```

The problem is because of:

```
[61] pry(main)> s << "\x99"
Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8
```

UPD: I solved the problem, adding **force_encoding('UTF-8')** to encode_to_s return, but still dont understand, why the problem appeared

Comment: Your code doesn't work the way you posted it, please fix it.

Comment: Thanks for editing your question, but I get `undefined method 'bytes' for 99:Fixnum` when passing an integer (99) to `encode_to_s`

Comment: What is `encode_to_s` supposed to do?

Comment: This should convert integer to BCD format.
Like this: 1234567890=>"\x12\x34\x56\x78\x90"

Comment: BTW, I think your code can be simplified: `[arg.to_s].pack('H*')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an encoding issue. Your `encode_to_s` method returns a binary string:

```
BCD.encode_to_s(99)          #=> "\x99"
BCD.encode_to_s(99).encoding #=> #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
```

Ruby's string literal on the other hand, creates UTF-8 encoded strings:

```
s = ""
s.encoding #=> #<Encoding:UTF-8>
```

This is probably not what you want. You can call [`String#b`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/String.html#method-i-b) to create a binary string:

```
s = "".b
s.encoding #=> #<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
```

Appending other binary strings should work without problems.